# Making UIAlertAction Handle work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, handle, uialertaction

I made an app for a local company several year ago. After a few year they let the app die due to money.But now they have decided to bring the app back, so I'm updating it a little for them. In the app I had where you could click on their number and it would call them. This is how I did it before. It still works, but say UIAlertView has been discontinued. And I'm afraid the app store will reject it.

```
-(IBAction)call
{
   BOOL isAppInstalled=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-731-307-3147"]];
   if(isAppInstalled)
   {
    UIAlertView *callNow = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"(731) 307-3147" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
    callNow.tag = 0;
    [callNow show];
   }
}
```

So now I have written it as this.

```
-(IBAction)Call
{
   BOOL isAppInstalled=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-731-307-3147"]];
   if(isAppInstalled)
   {
     UIAlertController* callNow = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"(731) 307-3141"                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:NULL];
    UIAlertAction* callAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Call" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:];

    [callNow addAction:cancelAction];
    [callNow addAction:callAction];
    [self presentViewController:callNow animated:YES completion:nil];
   } 
}
```

Where I am getting stuck is what do I put in the handle of the call button of the alert to make it do an action, like call the number? I've tried researching it and all I can find is what to do with swift. I made this app with Objective-C and would really not like to have to redo the whole app in swift. So I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to do this in objective-C.

Comment: that is a relatively good start to understand how blocks work in Obj-C: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIAlertAction* callAction = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Call"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:7313073141"]];

                             }];
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot you could use a URL for a phone number. I still had to work it a little bit because openURL has also been discontinued. but was able to figure it out. Thanks for getting me over that hump.